# Message ordering and kafka alternatives

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, message-queue

The number of messages passed are not large in number but there is need for strict ordering of messages on an entity. For example we may have a million messages but on 200K entities. If a message for an entity fails it subsequent messages should not be consumed but messages for other entities can be consumed.

With Kafka we get the ordering on an partition, with the limitation that if a message in a partition is not consumed then all the subsequent messages will be blocked, even if they belong to another entity. We can increase the number of partitions but this has a limit.

What are the generic patterns for solving these class of problems?

Comment: You can still "consumer" and ignore a message if you want to skip it -- for later processing. If you change your decision, you can remember the message offset and later `#seek()` to this offset to process the message later on.

Comment: As @MatthiasJ.Sax said -- you can actually skip a problematic message when you need to.  Hence it's a false assumption that "all the subsequent messages will be blocked".  Perhaps you need to update your question with a few more details, like what you added in your comment below?

Comment: Apologies for not giving enough information. Because ordering is required for an entity if I sideline a message, the subsequent messages for those entities need to be sidelined as well. As @ossu54 suggested I can keep track of the entities having a problem and every time I consume a message I can check against this list and decide to process or not. See my concerns with this in the comment to ossu54's answer
Does it clarify miguno and  Matthias J. Sax

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand the question correctly in that you want to ensure that messages for a certain entity go to the same partition while still having a scaleable solution.

The easiest way (in my opinion) to do this would be to specify the partition on the producer side.

```
new ProducerRecord(topicName, partitionId,messageKey,message)
```

If the specific topic in question comes from outside of your system and you can't thus create your own producer logic, I would just add a consumer which produces the messages to another topic so that the partition is specified.

Continuing with your example, let's say you have some_topic with million messages and 200k entities, you could have a high-throughput consumer which consumes everything and produces to some_topic_2 so that a message for a certain entity is always produced to the same partition.

Then you could use another high-throughput consumer which consumes from some_topic_2 and would do the logic you described, i.e. keeping tabs on which entities should be ignored and processing the other ones.

Of course if you don't have the need for a high-throughput system you could use a kafka topic with a single partition and do all the processing using a single consumer for that topic instead.

Relevant blogpost:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/3066873/big-data/big-data-messaging-with-kafka-part-2.html

Additional thoughts:

Another way to do this if you're using at least kafka 0.10 should be using Kafka Streams (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams).

> [...] being able to maintain state opens up many possibilities for sophisticated stream processing applications: you can join input streams, or group and aggregate data records.

I unfortunately have not worked with Kafka Streams API yet so I cannot specify an approach.

Hopefully other answerers can provide some additional insight.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've slightly different question. In the consumer for some_topic_2, I would have to keep tabs on which entities need to be ignored, so that I can move on to other entities which are not related but happen to be in the same partition. These I would need to store somewhere and check it for each entity adding overhead. Let's say if I created a million partitions then I wouldn't have this problem, but number of partitions are limited.
I can use a sorted set in redis for each entity so that one entity's failure does not impact others. Do you think this is a approach to consider?